# VBA Code to Copy and Paste Between Separate Excel Instances

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy data from one open instance in excel and load it into a separate open instance. I have the following code but it only copies data from the source workbook since the last save.  Also this code can only be run from the destination workbook.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub CollectA()

Dim oApp As Application
Dim oWb As Workbook
Set oWb = GetObject("Test two.xlsm")
Set oApp = oWb.Parent
oWb.Activate
oWb.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
Selection.Copy


Workbooks("Test three.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").PasteSpecial  Paste:=xlPasteValues


End Sub
```

Comment: Copy/paste is going to be difficult across different instances, but why do you even need to copy/paste - you seem to only want the values, so just use `Workbooks("Test three.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value = oWb.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value`.

Comment: Yes, I only need the values.  Thanks for the code simplification.  I'm still looking for a way to push data from the Source workbook.

Comment: If you want to do it the other way around, put the macro in the "Test two" workbook, and open the "Test three" workbook from there.

Comment: Thanks for the quick follow up.  Unfortunately when I run the new code it does nothing.  Also, for some reason after running the new code if I close the workbook 'Test Three' and try to reopen it I only see a grey Excel screen.

Comment: Why do you need to have the workbooks open in different instances of Excel?

Comment: I am attempting to run separate instances of Excel because I have a series of automated trading strategies that I've built into Excel.  Calculation speed is extremely important.  If I can run them in separate instances calculations done on one workbook wont affect the speed of calculations in a separate workbook.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid copy/paste whenever possible:

```
Sub CollectA()

    Dim oWb As Workbook
    Set oWb = GetObject("Test two.xlsm")

    Workbooks("Test three.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value = oWb.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value

End Sub
```

---

If you want the macro to be in "Test two":

```
Sub CollectA()

    Dim oWb As Workbook
    Set oWb = GetObject("Test three.xlsm")

    owb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value = Workbooks("Test two.xlsm").ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value

End Sub
```